# getInstance(this) not working on a class without activity

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-cardview

here is my class, I want to call a method from DatabaseAccess class:

```
public class CardAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

List<Person> mItems;
public Context context;

private static SQLiteDatabase database;
private SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;

public CardAdapter() {
    super();

    DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this);
    databaseAccess.open();

    List<String> kandidatet = DatabaseAccess.getKandidatet();
    database.close();

    Person p;
    mItems = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < kandidatet.size(); i++) {
        p = new Person();
        p.setName(kandidatet.get(i));
        mItems.add(p);
    }

 .....
....
 ...
  }
```

the error is in this row:

```
 DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this);
```

here is the method in the class DatabaseAccess:

```
private DatabaseAccess(Context context) {
    this.openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context);
}
```

It doesn't accept "this" as a context

how to fix this?

Comment: try `getactivity().getapplicationcontext()`

Answer (score 2):

It's because `this` must refer to object being of `Context` class or its child. `Activity` is subclass of `Context` your other classes are not. To work around this you can pass context to the adapter object upon its creation:

```
public CardAdapter(Context context) {
    ...

    DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(context);
```

Comment: I can't add context on the constructor because it messes all my other calls of the constructor

Comment: it this adapter class in separate file or it's your activity inner class?

Comment: it is a separate file

Comment: Then you got no much choice as you need to reference your application's  components. And you also cannot get context via static call. Alternatively you need to create own Application object and put i.e. `public static Context getAppContext() { return this; }` method. Then you can get the context by static call from your adapter. Still, this is bad approach

Comment: in which class should I use this method?

Comment: You need to extend `Application` (and set it up properly in manifest later on): https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Answer (score 2):

`this` refers to the class you're currently in. You **must** call `this` from an activity if you want it to be a valid `context` since activity implements `Context` interface.

Since you're calling it from a class which does not extend `Activity`, surely you get an error since `this` is not a `Context` in that case. You can fix this by calling the method with the field `context` you've declared above:

```
DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(context);
```

Before you do that, you'll need to initialize this field with a proper context, which you can do by changing the constructor to accept the `Context` :

```
public CardAdapter(Context ctx){
context = ctx;
//the rest of the code.
```

Be aware that now you also need to change the call of the constructor to `new CardAdapter(this)` if you're calling it from the activity (or `getActivity` if you're calling it from a Fragment).

Comment: I can't change my constructor because other classes uses it.

Comment: You must supply a context. Do it via setter. And then migrate this code from the constructor to a public method and call it after the setter. Either that or change the constructor on all places. Or use [Factory design pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm).

Comment: I have tried via setter method but it gives me every time null object

Comment: Remove the code from constructor. It's must be called before the setter, that's why the context is not set before calling the constructor. Move the code to another public method. You're not reading what I'm writing mate.